# Calculate Grouped mean and populate in new column in R

Tags: r, calculated-columns

I need a new column of mean grouped by months and the same mean for each month repeated n number of times the month appears.

the grouped mean is calculated but they are unique values, I am unable to make it repeat for n number times side by side for months.

```
tn_1$GAVG = aggregate(tn_1$FATALITIES, list(tn_1$MONTH), mean)
```

it gives the following error

```
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, GAVG, value = list(Group.1 = c("01",  : 
 replacement has 12 rows, data has 6267
```

the new column must display the mean for each month value.

```
 structure(list(FATALITIES = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
8L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 12L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
1L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 12L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 22L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
7L, 3L), MONTH = c("04", "04", "04", "04", "05", "05", "05", 
"05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06"
)), .Names = c("FATALITIES", "MONTH"), row.names = c(NA, 40L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Agree with above ^, a reproducible example would be helpful. You can use `dput()` on your dataframe to give you the code to reproduce your data. A sample of your data should be sufficient

Comment: My workaround has been `mg <- aggregate(tn_1$FATALITIES, list(tn_1$MONTH), mean)

names(mg) <- c("MONTH", "GAVG")

tn_1 <- left_join(tn_1, mg, by = ("MONTH"))`

Comment: I need a one liner

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`:

```
dat %>% group_by(MONTH) %>% mutate(avg=mean(FATALITIES))
# A tibble: 40 x 3
# Groups:   MONTH [3]
   FATALITIES MONTH   avg
        <int> <chr> <dbl>
 1          1 04     3.25
 2          2 04     3.25
 3          5 04     3.25
 4          5 04     3.25
 5          3 05     4.00
 6          3 05     4.00
 7          3 05     4.00
 8          4 05     4.00
 9          8 05     4.00
10          1 05     4.00
# ... with 30 more rows
```

Or, if you want to use base R only:

```
dat$avg<- ave(dat$FATALITIES, dat$MONTH, FUN=mean)
```

The latter is about 10 times faster:

```
microbenchmark(one=dat %>% group_by(MONTH) %>% mutate(avg=mean(FATALITIES)), two=ave(dat$FATALITIES, dat$MONTH, FUN=mean))
Unit: microseconds
 expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
  one 3698.875 4018.193 4438.3810 4283.864 4650.8455 10019.83   100
  two  265.885  326.586  458.7712  476.840  530.2735   820.31   100
```

Comment: Note that I added a faster base-R version.

Comment: If it is `ave`, you don't need the `FUN` as by default it is `mean` `with(dat, ave(FATALITIES, MONTH))`

Comment: True, but I like writing it in anyway, makes the code clearer for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try with base R `ave`

```
df$MEAN=ave(df$FATALITIES,df$MONTH,FUN=mean)
```